# Getting a negative decimal from a currency string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string with currency symbol. I need to extract just the decimal along with the negative sign.

Here are some examples of the string and the desired decimal value:

```
-$ 100 : -100 
C$ 400.68 : 400.68
-$ 578.89: -578.89
```

This is the code that I am using currently.

```
        var match = Regex.Match(valueToParse, @"-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            decimal.TryParse(match.Value, out result);
        }
```

It works for extracting decimal numbers but does not work for the 1st and 3rd example. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace everything except `-`, digits and `.` using this regex with empty string,

```
[^-\d\n.]+
```

which will leave you only with your desired number with negative sign.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKokja/1)**

[C# Demo](https://rextester.com/ZLOJ40869)

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^-\d\n.]+");
string input = "-$ 100";
string result = regex.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(input + " --> " + result);
input = "C$ 400.68";
result = regex.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(input + " --> " + result);
input = "-$ 578.89";
result = regex.Replace(input, "");
Console.WriteLine(input + " --> " + result);
```

Prints,

```
-$ 100 --> -100
C$ 400.68 --> 400.68
-$ 578.89 --> -578.89
```

Comment: Smart, thinking outside the box. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use capture groups for this. One for the sign and the other for the amount. Then you can concatenate both and try to parse it as a decimal.

The regex I'm using below has a couple of assumptions. But it should fit the use cases you brought forward.

```
var valueToParse = "-$ 578.89";
var match = Regex.Match(valueToParse, @"^(?<sign>-?).*? (?<amount>\d+(\.\d+)?)$");
if (match.Success)
{
    decimal.TryParse($"{match.Groups["sign"]}{match.Groups["amount"]}", out var result);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```